# Getting a null is not defined error when trying to run flask web app

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to build a web app that will clean up a csv and return graphs in pdf format.

Since I am new to building web apps and flask in general. I am trying to start off by building a simple web app that allows users to upload files of csv format. However, when I try to run the app on bash I get this error message:

```
(venv) bash-3.2$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    "execution_count": null,
NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

Here is the code I have used to build the web app I have thus far. I wrote this code in Jupyter, downloaded it as a .py file and tried running this file on bash

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
from flask import Flask, flash,redirect,render_template,request,url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
upload_folder = '/path/to/the/uploads'
allowed_exts = set(['csv','pdf'])
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['upload_folder'] = upload_folder
def allowed_f(file):
    return '.' in file and \
        file.rsplit('.',1)[1].lower() in allowed_exts
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('File part cannot be found')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No file has been selected')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_f(file.filename):
            filename =  secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['upload_folder'],filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',filename=filename))
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>GMB Discovery Report builder/title>
    <h1>Upload GMB Discovery CSV</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <input type=file name=file>
    <input type=submit value =Upload>
    </form>
    '''
from flask import send_from_directory
@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_f(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['upload_folder'],filename)
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Not sure which part of my code is resulting in this error message.

Edit running the command ipython main.py on dash returned this:

```
/Users/emmanuelsibanda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:763: UserWarning: Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please install IPython inside the virtualenv.
  warn("Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please "
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 29 2018, 19:04:46)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: The error is in `main.py`, in line 5. I guess what is shown here is not `main.py`?

Comment: @zvone it is main.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you downloaded the Jupyter Notebook file and saved it with a .py extension it doesn't only contain that script - it is only a small part of a larger .ipynb structure that the script is embedded within. Create a new file called main.py and copy the script into that file instead of downloading the notebook.

Comment: Tried this, now getting this error message when I try to run on bash : SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> python main.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python main.py

Comment: ctrl+z to exit python shell that you're trying to run it in. execute ```python main.py``` directly in your command prompt

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know is right there in the error message: Line 5 of your `main.py` module has `"execution_count": null` in it, which raises an error because apparently you have not defined a variable named `null`. Perhaps you are confusing it with the builtin `None` or meant to use the string `"null"` (note the quotes), that's impossible to tell without the code. Your snippet above must be something else, it does not contain the problematic line.

Comment: the snippet is my code, it does look different as a .py file (code written in jupyter)

Comment: Then you should explain in more detail where you have written that code and how you are running it. The `execution_count` line is part of Jupyter Notebooks (`.ipynb` files), it looks that you have confused something there. Please provide more details.

Comment: have added more detail

Comment: Ok, it looks like you are indeed accidentally trying to run the Jupyter Notebook directly, even though you have named it `main.py`. Jupyter Notebooks (normally ending in `.ipynb`) are JSON files, which contain the Python code, but also meta information about the notebook. They can not be run directly, and your error occurred on line 5 because everything before that is valid Python, whereas the unquoted `null` identifier is not. The question is how your notebook ended up being named `main.py`, is it possible that you have renamed it accidentally while moving it on the command line?