# Scrapy - Select item in form and extract the table that appears

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to extract information from a webpage where it requires me to select from a drop down list and based on the selection a table appears with various information. I have a list of selection values for the form/list on the page I would like to iterate through and extract the table information.

Web Page: https://www.mcafee.com/enterprise/en-us/support/product-eol.html

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider

product_names = ['Host Intrusion Prevention','McAfee Agent','Active Response','Database Security']

class McAfee_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'McAfee'
    allowed_domains = 'mcafee.com'
    start_urls = 'https://www.mcafee.com/enterprise/en-us/support/product-eol.html'

    for product in product_names:
        def parse(self, response):
            scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formxpath="//form[@id='selectProductArea']",
            formdata={
                "SelectProductArea" : product },
            clickdata = { "type": "select" },
            )

        def parse_table(self, response):
            product = response.xpath("//table[@class="general eoldynamicContent"]//tbody//tr//td[1]").extract()
            version = response.xpath("//table[@class="general eoldynamicContent"]//tbody//tr//td[2]").extract()
            eos_notif = response.xpath("//table[@class="general eoldynamicContent"]//tbody//tr//td[3]").extract()
            eol_date = response.xpath("//table[@class="general eoldynamicContent"]//tbody//tr//td[4]").extract()
```

I am stuck on how to form the xpaths for extraction. The examples I researched all have classes that I can access but this does not. Also, this site requires me to click from a form/list before a table appears based on the selection, I am using the "FormRequest.from_response" method but I am not sure if I set this up the correct way.

The information I want to extract is Product Name, Version Model, End of Support Notification, and End of Life/End of Support information. I would like to store the results in a dataframe first as I need to join information from other sources and then export into excel/csv.

Expected Result for the first product in the list "Host Intrusion Prevention" from https://www.mcafee.com/enterprise/en-us/support/product-eol.html

```
import pandas as pd
results = {'product':['McAfee Host Intrusion Prevention', 'McAfee Host Prevention for Linux'],
          'version':['8.0','8.0 Patch 6'],
          'eos_notif':['',''],
          'eol_date':['','']}
pd.DataFrame(results)
```

Comment: why are you declaring a class on each loop iteration?

Comment: your question is how does xpath work ? or how to choose the correct xpath to extract data?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest so the loop is there so I can pass in the product names for the selection in the form on the website. I want to able to scrape the table results of each of the product types I choose in the form.

Comment: @AmjasdMasdhash I am trying to extract the tables on the webpage based on the selection from the dropdown list

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I see the issue you mentioned. I moved the loop inside to iterate over the parse functions as I want a new form selection for each of the items in the list and then extract the table that appears after the selection

Comment: @C.Lee, post a fragment of expected output/result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I posted the expected result for 1 of the selections on the form, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're searching in a wrong place. Above website doesn't send any `FormRequest` after you select anything in a list. Instead it loads everything from a `https://www.mcafee.com/enterprise/admin/support/eol.xml` and just show piece of data:

```
import scrapy


class McAfee_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'McAfee'
    allowed_domains = 'mcafee.com'
    start_urls = ['https://www.mcafee.com/enterprise/admin/support/eol.xml']

    def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.xpath('//product'):
            product_title = product.xpath('./@title').get()
            for element in product.xpath('./element'):
                element_title = element.xpath('./@title').get()
                element_version = element.xpath('./@version').get()
                element_eos = element.xpath('./@eos').get()
                element_eos_notification = element.xpath('./@eos_notification').get()
                element_comment = element.xpath('./comment/text()').get()


                yield {
                    'product_title': product_title,
                    'element_title': element_title,
                    'element_version': element_version,
                    'element_eos': element_eos,
                    'element_eos_notification': element_eos_notification,
                    'element_commment': element_comment,
                }
```

Comment: Hi I tried to run the above code and am getting an error. "File "C:\anaconda3\Scripts\McAfee\McAfee\spiders\Scrapy_McAfee.py", line 5, in <module>
    "execution_count": null,
NameError: name 'null' is not defined"

Error states line 5, which is where we named the spider 'McAfee'. Not sure why this error is showing up. I am researching without success.

Comment: Fixed the issue, related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55856530/getting-a-null-is-not-defined-error-when-trying-to-run-flask-web-app